# Efficient way to extract area of raster in R

Tags: r, raster, r-sp, rgdal

I am trying to extract the area below 5000 feet for a 5 state area using the 30 meter (1 arc second) resolution NED (National Elevation Dataset), by state.  I have a shapefile of the states, and a large (about 4GB) raster of the NED.  I am using the velox package, which speeds things up significantly, but I feel there has to be a faster way to do this (it still takes a long time).

With the velox package, I make the raster into a velox object, then extract the cells using velox's extract function.  Since I know the resolution of each cell, I count the # of cells below 5000 feet in each state and multiply by the area of each cell.

```
DEM_velox <- velox(NED)
DEM_cells <- DEM$extract(DEM_velox,sp=state_shapefile)
```

Isn't there a better and much faster way to do this?  I know there's the area function from the raster package, and the gArea function from the rgeos package, but those are for polygons (shapefiles), not rasters, as far as I can tell.  Any help on this would be great.

Comment: It would probably speed things up to ```crop``` the NED by your 5-state region or by state so that you're dealing with a much smaller object and then ```mask``` the smaller raster(s) so that elevations outside the state boundaries are set to ```NA```.  Then you should be able to simply do a summation such as this to get the result: ```sum(values(cropped_masked_raster) <= 5000, na.rm=TRUE) * 30 * 30``` to get the area in m^2 that meet your condition

Comment: But in general, unless you have some serious computing power, it is going to be slow-going working with this 4 GB dataset.  Would be faster to have sets of smaller rasters that cover your AOI and work them in a loop so you are not overwhelming RAM.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of solving your problem for California using a loop with a set of smaller rasters (69 in total) that covered the entire state and avoiding `extract`.

Raster DEMs were downloaded from the NRCS Spatial Data Gateway.

The `extract` function was avoided through a `mask` of each raster that sets elevations outside the state boundary to `NA` before counting the number of cells below your critical elevation using `cellStats` along with the function `sum`.  This sums the number of cells below 5000' elevation, because the raster is converted to TRUE/FALSE values through `ras_masked <= crit_elev` before summation.  A separate test indicated the `extract` approach was 5-6 times slower than the `mask` approach.

The execution time for the loop was 400 seconds.

```
library(raster)
crit_elev <- 5000 / 3.2808 #critical elevation in meters
demDir <- yourDEMdirectoryHERE
CADir <- yourStateBoundaryDirectoryHERE
list.files(demDir)
fnames <-list.files(demDir, full.names = TRUE)[grepl('*.tif$', list.files(demDir))]
length(fnames) #69 rasters that cover CA but some do spill over state boundary, so mask is necessary

#read in state boundary and project to DEM crs
list.files(CADir)
CA_TA.shp <- shapefile(file.path(CADir, 'california_CA_TA.shp'))
CA_UTM11N <- spTransform(CA_TA.shp, crs(raster(fnames[1])))

#loop to solve the problem for CA
elev_count <- vector(mode='integer', length = length(fnames)) #this is where we will keep track of how many cells in each dem are below the crit_elev
system.time(for (i in seq_along(fnames)) {
  ras_masked <- mask(raster(fnames[i]), CA_UTM11N)
  elev_count[i] <- cellStats(ras_masked <= crit_elev, sum)
  print(i)
})
#user  system elapsed 
#175.76  224.67  400.70 
#count cells below 5000 ft, multiply by resolution (30 m) and divide by 10,000 to get hectares
sum(elev_count) * 30 * 30 / 10000 
#[1] 19247149
```

Comment: rather than the unsafe `sum(values(ras_masked) <= crit_elev, na.rm = TRUE)`, I would do `cellStats(ras_masked <= crit_elev, sum)`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Robert Hijmans.  Why is summing a logical vector considered unsafe?

Comment: What I referred to is the use of `values`. That can create memory overflow problems with large objects.

Comment: Thank you @Robert   I have tested your suggestion and edited the answer.  It produced the same result but 5 seconds faster.